# GCM register: block execution until it's finished

Tags: android, block, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM in my application. The first thing the user has to do is to log in in the app. When he sends the data, if the login is ok I call GCMRegistrar.register. If the device is successfully registered I'll open a new activity, otherwise I want to stay in the same activity and show an error message.

The problem I've found is that GCM register is asynchronous, and I want to stop the activity's execution until it's over. I tried the following:

```
GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
GCMApplication app = (GCMApplication) getApplication();
while(!app.isGcm_registered()){
    try {
         Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

When the registration is over I set gcm_registered to true in my applicaton class. But if I do this the register call is blocked, the function onRegistered from my GCMIntentService is never called. If I don't block the execution the register finishes successfully.

How can I block the activity's execution until the registration is over?

Comment: "I want to stop the activity's execution until it's over" -- that is an insanely bad idea. It may *never* be "over", as Internet access is not universally available. It may take an exceptionally long time (e.g., minutes), due to backlogs on the GCM server. Please allow the user to proceed in your app, at most disabling some features until GCM registration is complete.

Comment: +1 to what CommonsWare said. I'm afraid the OP misunderstands the inherently unreliable nature of GCM. For reliable, request-response-based, guaranteed-delivery-or-error communication with the server, may I recommend HTTP or a homegrown TCP-based protocol.